# .innerHTML not working

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

I have a very stupid problem. I would like to change the content of a table cell. My code:

```
        var x = ajax('...');

    alert(x);
    alert(document.getElementById(tdId).innerHTML);

    document.getElementById(tdId).innerHTML = x;
```

"x" has the right content => so ajax is working
And the second alert(...) gives also the right (actual) content. But when I would like to write x in the cell, nothing happens. No error, nothing...

I checked some similar problems here, but without success.

I have a realy no idea, what can I test further to understand the problem. Do you have an idea? Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: What _is_ the value of `x`

Comment: Are you sure the Ajax request is synchronous?

Comment: xmlHttpObject.open('get', url, false); => so it is synchronous...

Comment: x is a string: "Kugelgew.sp. 1000x16x5" => some strange character? I don't think so?! very strange...

Comment: Could you try it with `.textContent` to see if it works.

Comment: document.getElementById(tdId).textContent = x; => no success - also no error, no change of the cell content...

Comment: Do you have a live link?

Comment: set up a fiddle, so we can _see_ what you're working with. Also: don't use synchronous AJAX, please... try `xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){ document.getElementById(tdId).appendChild(document.createTextNode(this.responseText));};`

Comment: Well, all I can say is that to set value of `x` with a text instead of taking with ajax. Then if that works, there must be a problem about ajax.

Comment: @tcak => good hint: I wrote var x = "g"; it is also not working => so, I guess we can exclute ajax

Comment: @Sergio: No, sorry, it is running on localhost... :(

Answer (score 1):

I've got the solution!!!

This is very stupid: I changed the content of the td by clicking on the td... but the new content has a button to click again... now, firefox starts from the beginning on and shows the "second" content again...

Thats hard! :-)

However, I realy thank you very very much for your help! Sorry for wasting your time! :(

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = "Hello World";
var td = document.getElementById("myId");
var text = document.createTextNode(x);
td.appendChild(text);
```

if your script is on the top of the page, the DOM has not finished loading when you try to run your javascript function.

make sure your Javascript is running after the DOM has loaded:

```
window.onload += function(){
    var x = "Hello World";
    var td = document.getElementById("myId");
    var text = document.createTextNode(x);
    td.appendChild(text);
};
```

or, move your script file to the bottom of the page. (the first is more recommened)

Comment: Thanks for your idea... it tried it, but it also failed... I'm very lost :(

Comment: @minitech - creates a text node in the td to append the text.

Comment: Edited, Can you give it another try? it clearly works on the jsfiddle i supplied.

Comment: I just changed "myId" by tdId => nothing happened :(

Comment: is `tdId` a variable? or text? if it is a variable, you should remove the quotes for my code.

Comment: tdId is a variable... alert(document.getElementById(tdId).innerHTML) gives the right (current) content => so, it is not a problem of the id itself, I guess

Comment: is your javascript AFTER the HTML content?

Answer (score 0):

your code is correct, but make sure this element is not hidden (with display: none or visibility: hidden, for example). if you set a default value in the HTML file, will it appear?

you can also make a test adding the content of `x` to another element. try
`document.body.innerHTML += x` or even replace `x` to a string literal such as "this is a test".

Comment: also good hint "+=" => but still no success. The element is not hidden. Other question: if two elements have the same id, then I will get an error, right? So, we can exclude also this idea?

Comment: no you're not going to have an error. `x` will be applied to the first element with `tdId` id